# CallByName Unexpected results if argument is Variant array set to cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using CallByName in a particular application and getting results which I cannot explain.  They are reproducible on a simple test with the following conditions

- The property of the class object is of Type Double
- The value being added (Let) comes from a variant array that has been set to a multiple cell range

I would appreciate an explanation for this behavior.  The following code should reproduce it (at least in Excel 2007 / Windows 7)

Worksheet Cell **A1** contains **5.8**

**A2** contains **1.3** and the rest of the cells in column A are blank.

**Class Module** (class1)

```
Private pMyData

Public Property Get MyData()
    MyData = pMyData
End Property
Public Property Let MyData(Value)
    pMyData = Value
End Property
```

**Regular Module**

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
    Dim class1 As class1

Dim V(1 To 2, 1 To 1) As Variant
V(1, 1) = [a1]
V(2, 1) = [a2]

    Set class1 = New class1
    CallByName class1, "MyData", VbLet, V(1, 1)

    Debug.Print V(1, 1), class1.MyData  ' <-- 5.8           5.8

Dim W As Variant
W = Range("A1:A2")

    Set class1 = New class1
    CallByName class1, "MyData", VbLet, W(1, 1)

    Debug.Print W(1, 1), class1.MyData  ' <-- 5.8           312080296

    CallByName class1, "MyData", VbLet, CDbl(W(1, 1))

    Debug.Print W(1, 1), class1.MyData  ' <-- 5.8           5.8

End Sub
```

Note the 2nd debug.print line shows that the value stored in class1.MyData is 312080296 and not 5.8.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help or not, but I ran the test you posted and I'm getting a different number each time for the 2nd debug.print line. None of them were 312080296, but they were of the same magnitude. I haven't been able to figure out what the issue is, though, sorry.

Comment: @TheEngineer Thanks. Yes, I, too, get a different value for each run. I figure if we could explain the first value, we'd understand the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same thing here.  Getting 145842640.  If it helps you don't have to use CallByName.  Using the below line worked for me to set it correctly to 5.8.

```
class1.MyData = W(1, 1)
```

Might also help to declare pMyData a double, and also in Let/Get statments.  Then you'll get an error when attempting to assign, like the first V(1,1), which will force you to explicitly declare the conversion, which appears to be a good thing (or necessary even) in this situation.

Couldn't find a good quick reason why it is doing that though, or what the conversion is actually doing.    Hopefully someone knows, I'm curious now.

**EDIT** - It would appear that CallByName is actually passing the address of W(1,1) to the Let statement.  (Passing the value of the pointer, in other words.)  It would appear converting via CDbl dereferences the pointer, getting the value, which is why it works with the explicit conversion.  (Or so I think anyway.)

Try adding this function:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function VarPtrArray Lib "VBE7" Alias _
    "VarPtr" (Var() As Any) As LongPtr
```

Then do a debug.pring for W(1,1), and a debug.print for VarPtr(W(1,1)).  I found that the myData and the VarPtr value for W(1,1) were one and the same.  I assume this is part of the behavior of the CallByName function, as far as passing the address, not the value, but I don't have time to research further.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I would prefer not to use CallByName in general, because of the performance hit. But the nature of what I am working on makes the alternative unwieldy to write and debug.

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding VarPtr.  Once I found the correct declaration to use in VBA6, I find the same behaviour as you note. It seems odd that CallByName would pass a reference rather than the data in this seemingly very particular instance.  But thanks for the pointer to the pointers :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got this line to work correctly,

`CallByName class1, "MyData", VbLet, CVar(W(1, 1))`

Only thing I can think of is `CallByName` expects `Args()` as a `Variant`, and `W(1,1)` cannot be implicitly cast..(for some reason)

Comment: I noticed that statement about Args() being a variant.  But that seems incongruent with the fact that CDbl(W(1,1)) which clearly returns a Double, works fine.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, quite odd. The cast is implicit, is the only thing I can think of... Wondering if a `ByValue` thing. Still thinking

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, like the user above - im pretty sure its an implicit `ByValue` thing and doing explicit conversions gets `CallByValue` the right value to (implicitly) cast into a `Variant`. Although I do not have the time to finish looking into this. But interesting. +1

Comment: It is a BAD question, really. VBA Help file on **CallByName Function** explicitly states this: **args() Optional: Variant (Array)**. No guessing is required :) Besides, this function is antique and is kept for backward compatibility, no doubt; it should not be used in new code.

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky Yes, agree. Although I think OP did say this was not his preferred way of doing things, to be fair :-). I had never seen that function before!

Comment: Why would simple **class1.MyData = Range("A1").Value** would not be good enough?! Just as user3696061 pointed out above.

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky  That was how I started.  But I have 4 code segments of about 100 line each, which are identical except for a few properties; and in order to adapt them to changing data formats (over which I have no control), and still retain compatibility with the older data formats, I needed to make identical changes in each of the four groups. It seemed simpler to use a single subroutine, which took the different properties as arguments.  Then the changes only need to be made in the one segment.  I ran into this issue, and found a simple fix, but am wondering about the reasons.

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky It would not be the first time that MS Help was incomplete or otherwise misleading.  Clearly the argument can be other than Variant(Array).

Comment: @RonRosnfeld  I cannot recall an instance when VBA Help was wrong; maybe incomplete, but not wrong. It is possible the you can process arguments in CallByName function that are not in a Variant Array. This, technically, is "hacking". Why do it?! The documentation calls for Variant Array, and this ALWAYS works.

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky Probably I'm misunderstanding something. In the code line `CallByName Text1, "Move", vbMethod, 100, 100` what are the data types of the last two items?  I would have thought in VBA they would be of type Integer.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You've got me here!! Now I have one instance to remember when the Help is bad, truly. The example works but it is wrong nonetheless. Thank you!

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky Actually, the documentation calls for a **Variant(Array)**.  I don't know what that means.  I know what is meant by **Variant Array**, but I think the writers meant something different by the way they wrote it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I read it as an array of Variant Type. It can contain  any other Data types, of course. For example Array(100, 100) is a Variant that contains two Integer or Long values.

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky That was my first thought, but when I've seen that data type referenced in other parts of VBA Help, the parentheses around the word Array are not included, and the Example in Help clearly does not use a variant array.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld This is a relic, MicroSoft does not really support it; nobody cares about this function and I agee with them in this instance :)

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky I think this discussion is now outside the scope of StackOverflow, so although I disagree with you, I will not pursue it  further.

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky, I can think of one instance where VBA help was wrong. I wrote about it as part of [this post](http://yoursumbuddy.com/get-unique-per-row-values-removeduplicates/).

Comment: @DougGlancy **It is a beautiful post!** Thanks. Here is yet another one I did not know about... In my defence, I never used CallByName or RemoveDuplicates so obviously could not recall VBA help for those being wrong. I hardly ever use UsedRange, for example--it always works correctly with appropriate precautions are taken (too much trouble, though). I am sure there are more of these out there.